# Flutter Get Device MAC Address

Tags: dart, flutter

Does flutter have some code or additional package to get MAC address of the device?

Comment: Please check this out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19029

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Flutter can only do as much as what the underlying OS can, since iOS 7 and Android 6, you will always get the same response `02:00:00:00:00:00`, this has been made by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1) and [Google](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id) for privacy concerns.

Quote Apple

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device, the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager instead.)

Quote Google

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

Long story short, no MAC address available.

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily get Mac Address in flutter Using the get_mac Package. It supports IOS and Android.
Import in Your Dart File Where you want to get Mac Address.

then Refer to this Example-:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get_mac/get_mac.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  String _platformID = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "images/logo.png",
              height: 250.0,
              width: 250.0,
            ),
            Text(_platformID)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    try {
      platformVersion = await GetMac.macAddress;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get Device MAC Address.';
    }
    print("MAC-: " + platformVersion);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _platformID = platformVersion;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this package is outdated and does not work in null safety

Answer (score -3):

you can use package:  device_info_plus: ^3.1.1

Comment: Which variable? Please explain it here so your solution will be helpful