# Getting type error with flutter wifi package

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to run this example code which uses the flutter Wifi package. The example is based on n older version of the package but I am using the latest. Following is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Wifi',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _wifiName = 'click button to get wifi ssid.';
  String _ip = 'click button to get ip.';
  List ssidList = [];
  String ssid = '', password = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wifi'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          itemCount: ssidList.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return itemSSID(index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemSSID(index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('ssid'),
                onPressed: _getWifiName,
              ),
              Text(_wifiName),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('ip'),
                onPressed: _getIP,
              ),
              Text(_ip),
            ],
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              filled: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.wifi),
              hintText: 'Your wifi ssid',
              labelText: 'ssid',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (value) {
              ssid = value;
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              filled: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
              hintText: 'Your wifi password',
              labelText: 'password',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (value) {
              password = value;
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('connection'),
            onPressed: connection,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.wifi),
          title: Text(
            ssidList[index - 1],
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
          dense: true,
        ),
        Divider(),
      ]);
    }
  }

  void loadData() {
    Wifi.list('').then((list) {
      setState(() {
        ssidList = list;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _getWifiName() async {
    String wifiName = await Wifi.ssid;
    setState(() {
      _wifiName = wifiName;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _getIP() async {
    String ip = await Wifi.ip;
    setState(() {
      _ip = ip;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> connection() async {
    Wifi.connection(ssid, password).then((v) {
      print(v);
    });
  }
}
```

Application runs fine on my mobile, except for the listview, I have attached a screen shot of the app.

Please advise what is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssidList` contains `WifiResult` objects and not `String`. In order to display proper ssid you have to access the `.ssid` property:

Change `ssidList[index - 1]` into `ssidList[index - 1].ssid` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Kamil, trying that now. Is it possible to get MAC addresses instead of ssid?

Comment: As for now you can only get the ssid and level (not sure what's this) based on the class declaration https://github.com/once10301/wifi/blob/master/lib/wifi.dart#L53

Answer (score 0):

You have some types issues, ssidList should be `List<WifiResult>` not `List` this should work:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Wifi',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _wifiName = 'click button to get wifi ssid.';
  String _ip = 'click button to get ip.';
  List<WifiResult> ssidList = [];
  String ssid = '', password = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wifi'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          itemCount: ssidList.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return itemSSID(index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemSSID(index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('ssid'),
                onPressed: _getWifiName,
              ),
              Text(_wifiName),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('ip'),
                onPressed: _getIP,
              ),
              Text(_ip),
            ],
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              filled: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.wifi),
              hintText: 'Your wifi ssid',
              labelText: 'ssid',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (value) {
              ssid = value;
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              filled: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
              hintText: 'Your wifi password',
              labelText: 'password',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (value) {
              password = value;
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('connection'),
            onPressed: connection,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.wifi),
          title: Text(
            ssidList[index - 1].ssid,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
          dense: true,
        ),
        Divider(),
      ]);
    }
  }

  void loadData() {
    Wifi.list('').then((list) {
      setState(() {
        ssidList = list;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _getWifiName() async {
    String wifiName = await Wifi.ssid;
    setState(() {
      _wifiName = wifiName;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _getIP() async {
    String ip = await Wifi.ip;
    setState(() {
      _ip = ip;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> connection() async {
    Wifi.connection(ssid, password).then((v) {
      print(v);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Amin Is it possible to get MAC addresses instead of ssid?
Answer to your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409250/7807311

Comment: OK...So the MAC address I am looking for is not the device or connected network mac address but the ssid and mac addresses of all available hotspots. Is there a dart package that can do that?

Comment: @Amin till now there is no feature supported for this in flutter wifi package, and I have no idea about any other package that provides this feature in flutter