# flutter_blue get current device bluetooth MAC address

Tags: android, flutter

it is possible to get current device mac ID in flutter ? , my coworker says it's not allowed in android https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: from this SO post its not possible from android 6 and ios 7 due to privacy concerns https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409250/10409567

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fetch the device's bluetooth mac address as discussed on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409250) - which has been previously mentioned in the comments. However, if you're just looking for the ids of available bluetooth devices, it's possible by running a scan.

```dart
// Start scanning
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

// Listen to scan results
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // do something with scan results
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        debugPrint('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
});

// Stop scan
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```