# List Mac address of local network in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an application in Flutter that should list the devices connected to my WiFi network, in particular showing the devices' Mac. I would like to know how I can do this in Flutter or using another language like Java or C/C++ so that I can use it in my Flutter interface

I tried using several libraries in Flutter but none of them returned me to the device's Mac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Get Device MAC Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827236/flutter-get-device-mac-address)